# Displaying markers on click from the sidebar's elements

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In this v3 map(not finished): http://pp.gestion.webconcepteur.com/webconcepteur/styles/villerimouski/carte/carteTestClear.htm ,I want to be able to display just the markers I choose from a category in the right sidebar (select box).
Like this V2 version: http://www.ville.rimouski.qc.ca/styles/carte/carte.jsp.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Would start by searching Stack Overflow for answers, as this question has been asked before.  Try taking a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704292/dynamically-populated-google-maps-sidebar

Comment: @andresf My problem is not about populating the sidebar. I just want to display one marker at a time when I click on a sidebar's element.
I don't want all markers displaying when I choose a category of links.

Comment: Again, suggest you _search_ SO for the answer.  This is not a new question and something that people have implemented quite a bit.