# Google Maps Controls

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have found questions like this [Dynamically populated google maps sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704292/dynamically-populated-google-maps-sidebar)

Where they have a side bar. But none that actually do what I want. They all reference something like this: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_map2.htm

But what I need is the sidebar on the other side, which is "google ui" That I can just add html to.

Like the sidebar on https://maps.google.co.nz/ where you can click the arrow and it will hide.

Are there any examples on how to do this? Would that entire sidebar be a control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Google has implemented this functionality is by adding a `<div>` element with `position: absolute;` styling that contains the sidebar html.  They include a button for toggling that simply moves the panel off the screen.  The following jsFiddle should get you started on what you want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/x8rfd/4/

I haven't made it look pretty; this is just a demonstration of one way to make a panel show/hide with Google Maps.  You can position and style your button however you like, and put whatever content you want in the panel.

Keys to success for Google Maps API CSS: remember that your map canvas needs a height and a width:

```
#map-holder {
    position: absolute;
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
}
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer:

Here is a function that you can run on two elements and resize them at the same time

```
/*
* @param el1 the jQuery element to move (not null)
* @param el1 the jQuery element to resize (not null)
* @param pos the position to move it (not null)
* @param dur the duration to move it (not null)
* @param shw show or hide
* @param f1 function to call every x loops
* @param x see above
* @param f2 function to call once done
*/
Maps.ui.slide = function(el1, el2, pos, dur, shw, f1, x, f2){
    shw = (shw===null)?false:shw;
    x = (x===null)?1:x;
    f1 = (f1===null)?new function(){}:f1;
    f2 = (f2===null)?new function(){}:f2;
    dur = (dur===null)?1000:dur;
    dur = dur/pos;
    var p = pos/100;
    var t = 0;
    var r = x;
    var to = function(){
        if(!shw && t < 100){
            t += p;
            t = (t > 100)?100:t;
            el1.css("left", "-" + pos - (pos * t/100));
            el2.css("left", pos - (pos * t/100) );
            if(r == 0){f1();r=x;}else r-=1;
            setTimeout(to, dur);
        }else if(shw && t < 100){
            t += p;
            t = (t > 100)?100:t;
            el1.css("left",  pos - (pos * t/100));
            el2.css("left", (pos * t/100));
            if(r == 0){f1();r=x;}else r-=1;
            setTimeout(to, dur);
        }else if(t >= 100){f1();f2();}
    }
    setTimeout(to, dur);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Gave me an idea for what I really wanted.